# How to prevent Android Studio start emulator if forgot to plug phone cable

Tags: android-studio

Since months ago Android Studio has change something.

If I forgot to plug phone cable into computer (my job need replug frequently because of not enough port) when rushing to debug the app in phone, it will automatically run my emulator "Nexus 5 API 21" below:

[image]

I have to stop the emulator over and over again. It waste my time if I rushing something.

This happen quite a lot to me, so my question is how to prevent emulator run by default if phone cable not plugged yet.

Comment: [UPDATE] my previous workaround is naming emulator with e.g. **XXXXXXXX Pixel** long capital name to make it obvious this is emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow below steps to edit your app configuation:

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2:

[image]

Comment: This option seems disappeared in latest Android Studio 3.5 Beta 1.

Comment: Bug report filled at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144249612 . I need this option because now my Ubuntu keep disconnecting even plugged.